# Como executar uma função JavaScript a partid do meu Dropdown button?

Tags: javascript, html, electron

Tenho um DropdownButton feito em Css, segue o código html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="./mainScreen.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="./mainScreen.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="dropdown">
    <button onclick="dropdown()" class="dropbtn">Ordem de Serviço</button>
    <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
        <a id="create">Criar nova</a>
        <a id="list">Listar pendências</a>
        <a id="search">Pesquisar</a>
        <a id="close">Fechar</a>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Quero que quando uma dessas opções forem selecionadas, uma função num arquivo JS seja execuatada, para que eu possa realizar a comunicação IPC a partir do Electron e abrir a nova página do sistema.

Segue o atual código JS. Eu estava tentando executar perante o " onclick='osRequest()' ", porém provavelmente seria executado por completo por causa das verificações:

```
function osRequest() {
    if (document.querySelector("a#create")) {
        ipcRenderer.send("os:create");
    }
    if (document.querySelector("a#search")) {
        ipcRenderer.send("os:search");
    }
    if (document.querySelector("a#close")) {
        ipcRenderer.send("os:close");
    }
    if (document.querySelector("a#list")) {
        ipcRenderer.send("os:list");
    }
}
```

Comment: eu teria que criar um arquivo para cada função e usar o href em cada botão?

Comment: Você tentou usar o `addEventListener`?

Comment: Como usaria exatamente? Tipo, além do básico...

Comment: A [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/addEventListener) é um bom lugar para começar.